# CSS - Is the Font Weight property not necessary?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I was looking at some code, and saw someone mention the font-weight property in CSS

```
font-weight: normal;
```

Now, I just checked W3Schools, and they said font-weight: normal is default.

So does that mean you don't need to write that line at all?  Is it unnecessary?

Comment: That depends. If you have previously set `font-weight:bold`, you can set it back to normal with `font-weight:normal`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight

Answer (score 5):

W3schools is wrong, as usual. The *initial value* of `font-weight` is `normal`, but initial value is not the same as default. Browsers may have whatever default values they like for properties of elements. In practice, they tend to be relatively uniform in this. Typically, several elements such as `h1`, `strong`, `th`, and of course `b` have, by browser defaults, `font-weight: bold` set for them.

This means that if you do *not* want a first-level heading to appear in bold face, you need to declare the property explicitly:

```
h1 { font-weight: normal }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary when you have certain other styling options that could influence the text. It's better to have it there and make sure it doesn't get changed by anything else. And not every browser starts with all CSS the same way.